# Is there a script for packaging Magento Connect extensions?

Tags: magento

I understand how to create a Magento Connect package from a store admin (System-->Magento Connect-->Package Extensions).

Is there a script somewhere that accomplishes this? I would like to save the repeated typing of identical information into the fields, and just make the process more automated (for releasing multiple versions of the same plugin)

Comment: Never saw any separate package creator script. I assume the only way is to make custom calls to the `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Extension` and `Varien_Pear_Package`. Anyway after package was created once you can load all data from the package with "Load local package" tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(self link, but it's the only like it I know of)

There's nothing officially supported — that said I've created a script which can take a standard, flat, unix tar archive and create a Magento Connect package from it.  See the build examples on the [MagentoTarToConnect GitHub](https://github.com/astorm/MagentoTarToConnect).

The script is [magento-tar-to-connect.php](https://github.com/astorm/MagentoTarToConnect/blob/master/magento-tar-to-connect.php), and you feed it a configuration file like [example-config.php](https://github.com/astorm/MagentoTarToConnect/blob/master/example-config.php).  The configuration file has the minimum information needed to create a Magento Connect package, and should point at the unix tar archive (which you'll need to create separately).

If there's missing functionality I'm more than open to pull requests.